# How to draw Block diagram like this in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

I know basic LaTeX I tried to draw a block diagram similar to the one shown in diagram but I am unable to do it as one block is inside another I am getting problem in rendering. Please suggest any easy way to draw such block diagram. Thank you[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Here is an example of a diagram inside other boxes. http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/noise-shaper/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\tikzset{block/.style={draw,thick,text width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,align=center},
         line/.style={-latex}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[block] (a) {Dam};
  \node[block,right=of a] (b) {Checkdam};
  \node[block,right= 3cm of b] (c) {Checkdam};
  \node[block,right=of c] (d) {Dam};
  \node[block] (e) at ([yshift=-2cm]$(b)!0.5!(c)$) {Gate};
  \node[draw,inner xsep=5mm,inner ysep=8mm,fit=(a)(b),label={130:A}](f){};
  \node[draw,inner xsep=5mm,inner ysep=8mm,fit=(c)(d),label={50:B}]{};
  \node[draw,inner xsep=5mm,inner ysep=6mm,fit=(b)(c)]{};
  \draw[line] (a)-- (b);
  \draw[line] (b) -- (f.east);
  \draw[line] (f.east) -- (c)node[pos=0.4,above]{flow};
  \draw[line] (c)-- (d);
  \draw[line] (e)-- ($(b)!0.5!(c)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This one is for Paul:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\tikzset{block/.style={draw,thick,text width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,align=center},
         line/.style={-latex}
}
\makeatletter
\def\ruwave{\bgroup \markoverwith{\lower3.5\p@\hbox{\textcolor{red}{\sixly \char58}}}\ULon}
\font\sixly=lasy6
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[block] (a) {Dam};
  \node[block,right=of a] (b) {\ruwave{Checkdam}};
  \node[block,right= 3cm of b] (c) {\ruwave{Checkdam}};
  \node[block,right=of c] (d) {Dam};
  \node[block] (e) at ([yshift=-2cm]$(b)!0.5!(c)$) {Gate};
  \node[draw,inner xsep=5mm,inner ysep=8mm,fit=(a)(b),label={130:A}](f){};
  \node[draw,inner xsep=5mm,inner ysep=8mm,fit=(c)(d),label={50:B}]{};
  \node[draw,inner xsep=5mm,inner ysep=6mm,fit=(b)(c)]{};
  \draw[line] (a)-- (b);
  \draw[line] (b) -- (f.east);
  \draw[line] (f.east) -- (c)node[pos=0.4,above]{flow};
  \draw[line] (c)-- (d);
  \draw[line] (e)-- ($(b)!0.5!(c)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `fill`ing it looks like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc,backgrounds}
\tikzset{block/.style={draw,thick,text width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,align=center},
         line/.style={-latex}
}
\makeatletter
\def\ruwave{\bgroup \markoverwith{\lower3.5\p@\hbox{\textcolor{red}{\sixly \char58}}}\ULon}
\font\sixly=lasy6
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[block] (a) at(0,0) {Dam};
  \node[block,right=of a] (b) {\ruwave{Checkdam}};
  \node[block,right= 3cm of b] (c) {\ruwave{Checkdam}};
  \node[block,right=of c] (d) {Dam};
  \node[block] (e) at ([yshift=-2cm]$(b)!0.5!(c)$) {Gate};
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
   \node[draw,inner xsep=5mm,inner ysep=6mm,fit=(b)(c),fill=magenta!40]{};
   \node[draw,fill=olive,fill opacity=0.5,inner xsep=5mm,inner
     ysep=8mm,fit=(a)(b),label={130:A}](f){};
  \node[draw,fill=olive,fill opacity=0.5,inner xsep=5mm,inner
     ysep=8mm,fit=(c)(d),label={50:B}]{};
  \end{scope}
  \draw[line] (a)-- (b);
  \draw[line] (b) -- (f.east);
  \draw[line] (f.east) -- (c)node[pos=0.4,above]{flow};
  \draw[line] (c)-- (d);
  \draw[line] (e)-- ($(b)!0.5!(c)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're missing the spellchecker's zig-zag red underline... ;-)

Comment: @PaulGessler: Oh No!. I am caught. :-)

Comment: And I voted for that... :-(

Comment: @PaulGessler You got what you asked for :P

Comment: Great answer, when I try to add fill color in the fit box, it seems inside box will be in background. how can we just fill it as a background but keep inside box on top layer? e.g. "fill=red!10,fill opacity=0.9"

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks, it's perfect now.One more thing I think is if it's possible to use chain library to simplify the connection draw command? Then we can save more commands.

Comment: @Beatlej Nothing is impossible IMO. Have you tried it?